# Tariffs for ordering goods from switzerland to Germany

Tags: european-union, tax-law, germany, online, switzerland

I am a passionate Magic: The Gathering player and as is commonly known some of the older cards can have values of 100€ of euros. I am thinking about ordering such a card from switzerland for the price of 799€.
What I am concerned about is if I have to pay any tariffs and/or taxes since Switzerland is not part of the european union.

I know however that switzerland is part of many EU agreements and treaties, and I am wondering if there is one such treaty that affects my situation.

Comment: This is something you should ask the seller about.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment: different items have different tarifs, so the **exact** classification must be known (in the form of a number) to determine what percentage the tarif will have. The seller, who deals with EU exports should know this and supply it in the customs form (otherwise the EU customs will 'guess' what it is). I personally don't have the faintest clue as to what a **passionate Magic** is, so couldn't even start to guess in what range such a tarif would be.

Comment: @MarkJohnson: "Magic: The Gathering" is a collectible card game (yes it's spelled with a colon) and OP is saying they are a passionate player of the game.  So the item in question would be a card from that game (in the common sense, i.e. a printed piece of cardboard).

Comment: @NateEldredge Then this will probably be considered a **playing card**. With that information a trarif code can be found. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments:

- [Magic: The Gathering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering) are **trading cards** for a game

  - a google search '**eu tarifcode trading cards**' returns

    - [HS Code 95044000 - Playing, cards - Tariff Number](https://www.tariffnumber.com/2020/95044000)
  - a query at the eu tarifcode database [TARIC Consultation](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/taric_consultation.jsp?Lang=en) with

    - **95044000** and **Switzerland** returns

      - [playing cards, Switzerland](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&SimDate=20200914&Area=CH&MeasType=&StartPub=&EndPub=&MeasText=&GoodsText=&op=&Taric=95044000&search_text=goods&textSearch=&LangDescr=en&OrderNum=&Regulation=&measStartDat=&measEndDat=)

        - Switzerland (CH) Tariff preference (20-12-1972 - ) : 0 %
        - Third country duty (01-01-1999 - ) : 2.70 %

          - United States 10.0 %

Based on this information there should be no **customs tarifs** to pay when importing from Switzerland to Germany.

You may be required to pay the German VAT of 16% (until 2020-12-31). The Swiss VAT of 8% should **not** be part of your bill.

---

**Sources**:

- [Magic: The Gathering - Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering)

  - [HS Code 95044000 - Playing, cards - Tariff Number](https://www.tariffnumber.com/2020/95044000)
- [TARIC Consultation](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/taric_consultation.jsp?Lang=en)

  - [playing cards, Switzerland](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/dds2/taric/measures.jsp?Lang=en&SimDate=20200914&Area=CH&MeasType=&StartPub=&EndPub=&MeasText=&GoodsText=&op=&Taric=95044000&search_text=goods&textSearch=&LangDescr=en&OrderNum=&Regulation=&measStartDat=&measEndDat=)